# Issue compiling TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, eigen3, bazel

I'm getting an error when compiling TensorFlow.
I get to the command:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-march=native' '-std=c++0x' '-march=native' -MD -MF bazel-out/local-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/reduction_ops/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/local-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/reduction_ops/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.pic.o' -fPIC -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY -DTENSORFLOW_USE_JEMALLOC -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/local_config_sycl -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/local_config_sycl -iquote external/jemalloc -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/jemalloc -iquote external/protobuf -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf -iquote external/gif_archive -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/gif_archive -iquote external/jpeg -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/jpeg -iquote external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/farmhash_archive -iquote external/highwayhash -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/highwayhash -iquote external/png_archive -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive -iquote external/zlib_archive -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/zlib_archive -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/jemalloc/include -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/jemalloc/include -isystem external/protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/src -isystem external/gif_archive/lib -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/gif_archive/lib -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem external/highwayhash -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/highwayhash -isystem external/png_archive -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive -isystem external/zlib_archive -isystem bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/zlib_archive -DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY -Iexternal/gemmlowp -Wno-sign-compare -fno-exceptions -pthread -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.cc -o bazel-out/local-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/reduction_ops/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.pic.o
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_common.h:26:0,
                 from tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.cc:16:
./third_party/eigen3/Eigen/Core:1:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
```

I've looked within `Eigen/Core` and it contains only one line:

```
> cat third_party/eigen3/Eigen/Core 
#include "Eigen/Core"
```

Has anyone had a similar issue and managed to solve?

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: Did you actually run that command? Or that is what bazel is executing? If you run it by hand, can you building with bazel? If you run it with bazel, what version of bazel and what version of tensorflow are you building?

Comment: It is Bazel executing, and also I've run the command myself, both with the same results. I'm using the newest Bazel (it's at home so I'll write later) and I'm trying to build tensorflow HEAD (pulled last week).

Comment: @mhlopko Bazel ver: 0.4.5 TF : branch r1.0 (also HEAD has the same problem) Ubuntu ver: 16.04

Comment: I just saw that which gcc v 5 and up i need to add -cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0". I'm not sure where to add this line?

Comment: I added the above line in the correct place and still am getting the same error

Comment: I don't know if you need to this manually (I'm not using bazel), but have you tried extracting a version of Eigen into `external/eigen_archive` of your local build-tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Eigen3 manually and then I changed the compiler flags to contain the correct include path just before calling bazel.